# Up and Down animation on Android view

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I'm making a Splash Screen and I want the image view to continuously go up then down like it's levitating. This will happen while the database loads in the background (AsyncTask). I have tried animating views but it is only in a single direction and just once. How do I accomplish this? Thank you in advance :D

Comment: I edited my answer and changed the code a bit

Comment: all i have to do is to change the timing but it works as i wanted to. thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is animate views like you did before,with a kind of an infinite loop inside onAnimationEnd :

```
 //in onPreExecute do levitate(ivSplashLogo, 300, true)
 //in onPostExecute do levitate(ivSplashLogo, 300, false)

 public void levitate (final View movableView,final float Y,boolean animated){
   if(animated) {
        final long yourDuration = 200;
        final TimeInterpolator yourInterpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator();
        movableView.animate().
                translationYBy(Y).
                setDuration(yourDuration).
                setInterpolator(yourInterpolator).
                setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        levitate(movableView, -Y, true);
                    }
                });
    }
 }
```

I haven't tried this yet but you could give it a go and tell me

Comment: I am unaware of what Interpolator is for and how it differs from Duration.

Comment: An Interpolator is a Bezier curve that will apply different effects to the animation. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMOJxBe9KGg) is a video that will show you the results of various interpolators. Here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html) if you want

Comment: i see. thanks! im calling it from the OnProgressUpdate but it's not moving :<

Answer (score 2):

Bottom to top :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

Top to Bottom :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

Code :

```
if (findViewById(R.id.llIncludeBottom).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    findViewById(R.id.llIncludeBottom).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.llIncludeBottom).setAnimation(
                            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.top_bottom));
                } else {
                    findViewById(R.id.llIncludeBottom).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.llIncludeBottom).setAnimation(
                            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bottom_top));
                }
```